# Reproduce playlist from terminal in Banshee

Tags: command-line, banshee

That's it, how can I play a specific playlist from terminal in Banshee? I've seen the --help pages and it didn't help much, so I wanted to know if anyone here knew it.
Is it useful? For me it is, I'd use "Remote Launcher" (Android) to reproduce playlists faster and without a need for a screen.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
banshee file://(the path to and name of your playlist)
```